# How do I change the unity launcher icon back to the default?

Tags: unity, launcher, edubuntu

[image: What the Unity Launcher icon currently looks like.]

I recently installed the `edubuntu-artwork`pack along with the`edubuntu-wallpapers`package. The Unity Launcher icon immediately switched to the Edubuntu logo. My question is, how do I switch this back to the original Ubuntu logo?
Also, the login screen shows the edubuntu banner on it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon file changed is: `/usr/share/unity/6/launcher_bfb.png`

I can suggest two ways in which you can restore this:

1. Manually, by copying and pasting this file:
   http://ubuntuone.com/1NYCV5AwIKqAWMoXtk7YNY
2. Automatically, by re-installing unity

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Is there a way to fix the problem with the login screen as well?

Comment: Could you please upload the 13.04 launcher icon? The icon reverted to a question mark when I upgraded.

Comment: OK. Edited the answer to change url link to Ubuntu 13.04 icon.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the banner with ubuntu tweak.

1.Install it with this command from your terminal

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/0.8.x/0.8.3/+download/ubuntu-tweak_0.8.3-1~precise1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ubuntu-tweak_0.8.3-1~precise1_all.deb
```

Now you got it installed.

Type as Ubuntu Tweak in your unity dash and it will list you that , Then now click at Tweaks and Unlock it.

There you can customize it as you want.If you would like to get the default one then just click at The current background and choose default background from the list.

Hope that helps you.

[image]

Comment: Well that's completely up to you.

if you like you can offer more with bounty .

Comment: Actually, it didn't change the login screen. Is there a folder I can go to to manually edit it?